# Wordpress - Adding meta box to certain post category

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I have added a category called 'Case Studies' in the post administration section.

Is there any way to add a meta box in the 'add new post' screen for ONLY the posts in the 'Case Studies' category?

Cheers,